# years (of) experience

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am struggling to understand this. Let's imagine that it's been over 10 years since I started working on something and I want to say that. For me, the following comes to mind:

> I have over 10 years of experience on..

I ask that because most of my searches on google about this ended up with results pointing that this is the case more used:

> I have over 10 years experience on...

Is the first situation incorrect? Can I use both cases? Which is the one more accepted grammatically (for English tests purpose)? Can someone explain me why?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your "over 10 years of experience" is fine. The other alternative should include an apostrophe: "over 10 years' experience". See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/119751/11482.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27652/5-years-experience-in-or-5-year-experience-in-or-5-years-of-experience-in/30988#30988

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have over 10 years of experience - is preferred

Because the preposition *of* will connect the experience with its period. As Damkerng suggests, if you want to remove *of*, put the possessive apostrophe *s*.

However, be cautious using *experience on*. There exists *experience of* or *experience in* as well. It's *[debatable](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1430151).*

> I have over 10 years of experience in (the field of) marketing. 
>   I have over 10 years of experience of conducting seminars.

I think we use *experience in something* and *experience of doing something*.

Comment: It's good that you mentioned the choice of preposition. However, I'm not sure if "experience on" is debatable. According to the link you gave, it's about "experience of" vs. "experience in" (also "experience with"). I'd suggest "experience in" If it's about knowledge and skill.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Oh yes, a typo. I missed it. thanks. corrected. I was aware of that in giving the example but somehow missed it.