# "5 years experience in" or "5 year experience in" or "5 years of experience in"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Not sure which one is the right one?

-I have 5 years experience in playing chess.

-I have 5 year experience in playing chess.

-I have 5 years of experience in playing chess.

It seems that the 2nd and the 3rd is ok, but I am not so sure

Answer (score 3):

Here are some facts would make it more clearer:

**Years** are **countable** so using 5 years would be correct.

Oxford dictionary says:

> **[countable, usually plural]** age; time of life
>
> -He was 14 years old when it happened.
>
> -She looks young for her years.
>
> -They were both only 20 years of age.
>
> -A twenty-year-old manHe died in his sixtieth year.
>
> -She's getting on in years (= is no longer young).

**Experience** can be used as both **countable** and **uncountable**

**Countable forms:**

> **[countable]** an event or activity that affects you in some way
>
> -an enjoyable/exciting/unusual/unforgettable, etc. experience
>
> **experience (of something):**
>
> -It was her first experience of living alone.

**Uncountable forms:**

> **[uncountable]** the knowledge and skill that you have gained through doing something for a period of time; the process of gaining this
>
> -to have more than ten years of teaching experience
>
> -Do you have any previous experience with this type of work?

**also**

> **[uncountable]** the things that have happened to you that influence the way you think and behave
>
> -Experience has taught me that life can be very unfair.
>
> -It is important to try and learn from experience.

So here we are looking for the first uncountable form which fits exactly what we are looking for.

**Which gives us the result:**

> -I have 5 years of experience in playing chess.

Answer (score 2):

I would write "five years' experience" (With the apostrophe) but these days people are often eliminating apostrophes altogether.

Comment: +1 And we normally use the ’s genitive with words that specify a time periods. *A day's work. A three week's holiday*, etc.

Comment: "I have five years(' | of) chess(-playing) experience."

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung you beat me to it. xD